# Delphi, формула, ошибка [Error] Unit1.pas(90): Undeclared identifier: 'Power'

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);

var a,b,c,d,rez:real;
begin

if Application.MessageBox('Вы подтверждаете расчет функции?',
'Подтвердите операцию',  MB_YesNo+MB_IconQuestion+MB_DefbUtton2)=IdYes then
begin

a:=StrToFloat(Edit1.Text);
b:=StrToFloat(Edit2.Text);
c:=StrToFloat (Edit3.Text);
d:=StrToFloat(InputBox('Введите четвертое значение для расчета','Окно ввода','1'));
rez:= (7+Exp(Sqrt(a)+1))/(Sqrt(Power(Ln(Power(b,2)-5),3)-4)+ Sin(Power(c,2)))+Power(sin(d),(3/4));
Edit4.Text:=FloatToStr(RoundTo(rez,-3));
end;


end.
```

Выбивает ошибку

```
[Error] Unit1.pas(90): Undeclared identifier: 'Power'
```

Answer (score 2):

Если поставить курсор на `Power` и нажать F1, то вызовется справка, в которой написано, что функция `Power` объявлена в модуле `Math`.

Следовательно, в список `uses` в начале программы (точнее - модуля формы) нужно добавить `Math`